# Why this syntax error? No given reason from the shell

Tags: ocaml, ocamlbuild, ocamllex

I've just finished writing this piece of pattern matching (to be attached below). No matter how I tried fixing it up, there is still "Error: Syntax error" when I tried to compile it.

The piece of code is here:

```
let rec stmt (s:Ast.stmt) : X86.inst list = 
        let get_label e = 
            let inst = stmt e in 
            let pattern = (List.nth (List.rev inst) 0) in
            let label = match pattern with 
                        |Memory (Store (Addr (Label l), Reg r)) -> l 
                        |_ -> "Error"
        in 
        match s with
        |Exp e -> (match e with
                |Int i -> [movei RAX i; store new_temp() RAX]
                |Var v -> [load RBX v; store new_temp() RBX]                
                |Binop (e1, op, e2) -> let (label1, label2) = (get_label e1, get_label e2) 
                                        in let operation = 
                                          match op with
                                          |Plus -> [Arith (Add (RAX, Reg RBX))]
                                          |Minus -> [Arith (Sub (RAX, Reg RBX))]
                                          |Times -> [Arith (Mul RBX)]
                                          |Div -> [Arith (Div RBX)]
                                          |Eq -> [Arith (Cmp (RAX, RBX))]
                                          |Neq -> [Arith (Cmp (RAX, Reg RBX)); set NE RAX] 
                                          |Lt -> [Arith (Cmp (RAX, Reg RBX)); set L RAX]
                                          |Lte -> [Arith (Cmp (RAX, Reg RBX)); set LE RAX]
                                          |Gt -> [Arith (Cmp (RAX, Reg RBX)); set G RAX]
                                          |Gte -> [Arith (Cmp (RAX, Reg RBX)); set GE RAX]
                                        in [load RAX label1; load RBX label2] @ operation @ [store (new_temp()) RAX] 
                                        

                |Not e -> let label = get_label e in
                          [load RBX label; Arith (Neg RBX); store (new_temp()) RAX] 
                |And (e1, e2) -> let (label1, label2) = (get_label e1, get_label e2) in
                          [load RAX label1; load RBX label2; Bitop (And (RAX, Reg RBX)); store (new_temp()) RAX]
                |Or (e1, e2) -> let (label1, label2) = (get_label e1, get_label e2) in
                          [load RAX label1; load RBX label2; Bitop (Or (RAX, Reg RBX)); store (new_temp()) RAX]
                |Assign (e1, e2) -> let label = get_label e2 in
                          [movei RAX label; store e1 RAX; store (new_temp()) RAX] 
                |_ -> [])
        |Block e  -> []
        |If (l, m, r) -> []
        |While (l, r) -> []
        |For (l, m1, m2, r) -> []
        |Return e -> []
        |_ -> []

let compile (p : Ast.program) : result =
    let _ = reset() in
    let _ = collect_vars(p) in
    let insts = List.concat_map stmt p in
    { code = insts; data = VarSet.elements !variables }
```

Error is at `let compile (p: Ast.program) : result =`

which is this (from the shell):

```
110 | let compile (p : Ast.program) : result =
      ^^^
Error: Syntax error
```

Answer (score 1):

The error follows from not having properly completed the `get_label` function:

```
        let get_label e = 
            let inst = stmt e in 
            let pattern = (List.nth (List.rev inst) 0) in
            let label = match pattern with 
                        |Memory (Store (Addr (Label l), Reg r)) -> l 
                        |_ -> "Error"
```

Hence the `in` following it is associated with `let label = ...`, not `let get_label e = ...`, despite your indentation.

I suspect what you want is to just skip the `label` binding:

```
        let get_label e = 
            let inst = stmt e in 
            let pattern = (List.nth (List.rev inst) 0) in
            match pattern with 
            | Memory (Store (Addr (Label l), Reg r)) -> l 
            | _ -> "Error"
```

It might be a good idea to use a tool like [`ocp-indent`](https://www.typerex.org/ocp-indent.html), which will indent your code according to how the compiler will interpret the code, not how you want the compiler to interpret it. That usually helps to avoid mistakes like this :)

Comment: Duh on myself! Thanks for the quick response. You're totally right. I was so angry at my machine at the time for the bug: stupid me! it's a machine, unlike us.